# Config xampp never to cache pages from localhost

Tags: apache-http-server, cache, xampp

I am not a webmaster, and that was exactly the reason why I installed XAMPP 1.7.2 on Windows XP SP2 instead of manually configuring Apache, MySQL and PHP to cooperate each other.

Now I am having to problem to disable caching pages from localhost.

Some suggested just force the browser not to cache, using Firefox web developer bar or something similar; but I feel it would be better if I could configure the Apache server in XAMPP to never allow pages from localhost to be cached.

I guess this is done somewhere in httpd.conf?

```
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
```

Would this module be helpful in this case?
Doc here : [mod_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cache.html)

I am not very sure this would resolve the problem. Could anyone confirm this approach feasible? I'd like to work it out myself, given the fact that I am on the right track...

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mod_cache at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cache.html

`CacheDisable /local_files`

Description: Disable caching of specified URLs
Syntax:  CacheDisable url-string
Context: server config, virtual host

Answer (score 2):

Do you  need to uncomment the module? In my `http.conf` file the module is commented out with a #:

```
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to:
CacheDisable /local_files

..yes, I had to un-comment (remove the pound symbol from) the following to get it to work:
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so

Thank you so much, all!!